# Regarding static and dynamic binding in Java

Tags: java

Please explain the concept of static and dynamic binding in Java.

What I have grasped is that Static binding in Java occurs during compile time while dynamic binding occurs during Runtime, static binding uses Type (Class in Java) information for binding while dynamic binding uses Object to resolve binding.

This is the code for my understanding.

```
    public class StaticBindingTest {

    public static void main (String args[])  {
       Collection c = new HashSet ();
       StaticBindingTest et = new StaticBindingTest();
       et.sort (c);         
    }

    //overloaded method takes Collection argument
    public Collection sort(Collection c) {
        System.out.println ("Inside Collection sort method");
        return c;
    }     

   //another overloaded method which takes HashSet argument which is sub class
    public Collection sort (HashSet hs){
        System.out.println ("Inside HashSet sort method");
        return hs;
    }         
}
```

and the output of the above program was inside the collection sort method

for dynamic binding...

```
    public class DynamicBindingTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Car(); //here Type is vehicle but object will be Car
        vehicle.start();       //Car's start called because start() is overridden method
    }
}

class Vehicle {

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Inside start method of Vehicle");
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println ("Inside start method of Car");
    }
}
```

the output was inside the start method of Car. Please advise: Is this understanding correct and please advise some more examples. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be the norm these days on SO...

Answer (score 0):

Static binding is used at compile time and is usually common with overloaded methods - the sort() methods in your example where the type of the *argument(s)* is used at compile time to resolve the method.

Dynamic binding ([dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_binding_%28computer_science%29)) is usually associated with polymorphism and overriding methods - the start() method in your example where the type of the *receiver* (vehicle) is used at runtime to resolve the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have summarized it correctly and shams also correctly added more information for you. Just to add little more information for you first let me step back by stating that the association of method definition to the method call is known as binding. So, static binding as you pointed out correctly, is the binding that can be resolved at compile time by compiler (also known as early binding or static binding). On the other hand, dynamic bidding or late binding it means compiler is not able to resolve the call/binding at compile time (it happens at the run time). See below for some examples:

```
//static binding example
class Human{
....
}
class Boy extends Human{
   public void walk(){
      System.out.println("Boy walks");
   }
   public static void main( String args[]) {
      Boy obj1 = new Boy();
      obj1.walk();
   }
}  

//Overriding is a perfect example of Dynamic binding
package beginnersbook.com;
class Human{
   public void walk()
   {
       System.out.println("Human walks");
   }
}
class Boy extends Human{
   public void walk(){
       System.out.println("Boy walks");
   }
   public static void main( String args[]) {
       //Reference is of parent class
       Human myobj = new Boy();
       myobj.walk();
   }
}
```

[source](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-dynamic-binding)